# When will 'Max_execution_time_set_failed' status variable be incremented in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization

Server: Mysql 5.7

By [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Max_execution_time_set_failed), it has been said that

> The number of SELECT statements for which the attempt to set an
>   execution timeout failed.

Can anyone explain the scenarios or share queries for which there is a possibility of this failure and thereby incrementing this variable. I have attempted myself but I couldn't find it.

Comment: This url describes the Global Variable - max_execution_time (in ms) that would increment Global Status variables related to the subject.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html

Comment: This url includes documentation on how to put the 'HINT' in your query, if needed rather than in the Global Variables when digging deeper.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizer-hints.html#optimizer-hints-execution-time